# Ifstream hitting eof early

Tags: c++, file

I'm trying to read in a BMP image file into memory however my code keeps hitting eof early. The pixels that it does read seem to be correct. eof is encounter at the same place of each file repeatedly however there is not a common pattern that is repeatable between files.

```
1024 x 1024 image: file length = 3145782, bytes read = 6154.
256 x 256 image: file length = 196662, bytes read = 24243.
256 x 256 image2: file length = 196662, bytes read = 931.
```

I just cannot work out whats going on an would appreciate some input.
Below is a shortened version of my code. I've only removed things like safety checks for sake of readability.

```
std::ifstream file(filename, std::ios::in || std::ios::binary);

file.seekg(0, file.end);
int length = file.tellg();
file.seekg(0, file.beg);
std::cout << "file length = " << length << "\n";

//Read Header in and confirm this is actuall a bmp file.
file.read((char*)header, 54);

dataPos = *(int*)&(header[0x0A]);
imageSize = *(int*)&(header[0x22]);
width = *(int*)&(header[0x12]);
height = *(int*)&(header[0x16]);

std::cout << imageSize << "," << width << "," << height << "\n";

data = new unsigned char[imageSize];
file.read((char*)data, imageSize);
std::cout << "bytes read: " << file.gcount() << "\n";

file.close();
```

Comment: you're using the logical || operator in place of the bitwise | operator in the stream flag parameter

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes my god, thank you. if you post a answer i'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> std::ifstream file(filename, std::ios::in || std::ios::binary);

you're using the logical || operator in place of the bitwise | operator in the stream flag parameter. If the bitmask turns out to be implemented as an integer or plain enum type, no error will occur and the resulting flag will be converted to 1 ( whatever such a flag value is supposed to mean on your implementation ).